# Python Requests: No permission to access URL & unicode error

Tags: python, web-scraping, unicode, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My goal is to scrape the macys.com website, and I can not get access. The following code is my initial attempt.

**Attempt 1**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.macys.com').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

This resulted in the following error.

```
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>
You don't have permission to access the requested URL on this server.
<p>Reference: 18.c503d417.1587673952.4f27a98</p>
</body>
</html>
```

After finding similar issues on stackoverflow, I see the most common solution is to add a header. Here is the main code from that attempt.

**Attempt 2**

```
url = 'https://www.macys.com'
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

Here is the last error message I have received. After researching the site, I am still unsure how to proceed.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x92' in position 586833: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am very intro level, so I appreciate any insight. I am also just genuinely curious why I don't have permissions for macys site as testing other sites works fine.

Comment: Try prefixing the headers with b, like this `headers = {b'User-agent': b'Mozilla/5.0'}`.

Comment: @VojtechKane Just gave it a shot. Still the same error.

Comment: What Python version are you using? I tried it now with Python 2.7 and while I could reproduce the `Access denied` error, your second attempt worked just fine.

Comment: I am using python 3.8

Comment: If this helps I just ran a status code on my request. I received #302 on attempt 1 code.

Comment: Always check the traceback. And you should include it here. I suspect that the UnicodeEncodeError is being raised by the last line of your code snippt, the `print()` statement. Which means that retrieving and parsing the content worked; only printing the result failed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your *Attempt 2* code, and it works fine for me.

Try setting the BeautifulSoup's `from_encoding` argument to `utf-8`, like so:

```py
url = 'https://www.macys.com'
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml', from_encoding='utf-8')

print(soup)
```

> I am also just genuinely curious why I don't have permissions for macys site as testing other sites works fine.

This is something the administrators for Macy's have done to prevent bots from accessing their website. It's an extremely trivial form of protection, though, since you only need to change the `user-agent` header to something typical.